# Does COPPA require that users who provide PII while under 13, then turn 13 have their PII purged?

Tags: personal-information, coppa

If there is a user of an online website who provides PII while under the age of 13, then later turns 13, would COPPA require that that person have their PII purged from that online website?

Comment: Can you cite something from the coppa regulations that make you draw that conclusion?